# How to combine specific rows in one dataframe

Tags: r

How to combine two specific rows in one dataframe?

e.g.I want to specifically merge A and Ab rows only not the other rows.

| name | x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A. | c | NA | n |
| Ab | NA | r | k |
| C. | m | o | w |

the result I am looking for

| name | x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A. | c | r | n |
| C. | m | o | w |

sample of my dataset as follow which I want to combine 'aring' with 'aring a', 'aring b' with 'aring b - kelantan':

```r
t1 <- structure(list(name = c("archipelago", "arindo trisejahtera tg malim", 
"aring", "aring a", "aring b", "aring b kelantan"), `Mill ID` = c("4696", 
"3410", NA, "3432", "4328", NA), `Mill name.x` = c("archipelago", 
"arindo trisejahtera (tg malim)", "aring", "aring a", "aring b", 
"aring b - kelantan"), `Mill name.y` = c("archipelago", "arindo tri sejahtera", 
NA, NA, NA, NA), Latitude = c("-1.1395200000000001", "0.58055999999999996", 
NA, "4.9408300000000001", "4.9363999999999999", NA), Latitude.x = c(-1.1395156, 
0.580944444, 4.940494, Inf, Inf, 4.9364), Latitude.y = c("-1.1395200000000001", 
"0.58055999999999996", NA, NA, NA, NA), Longitude = c("113.98648", 
"100.92610999999999", NA, "102.36417", "102.4256", NA), Longitude.x = c(113.9864769, 
100.9246944, 102.362839, Inf, Inf, 102.4256), Longitude.y = c("113.98648", 
"100.92610999999999", NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = 176:181, class = "data.frame")
```

my final solution based on @Ronak Shah

```
library(dplyr)

values_to_combine <- c('A.', 'Ab')

df %>%
  group_by(name = replace(name, name %in% values_to_combine, 'A.')) %>%
  summarise(across(x:z, ~toString(na.omit(.)))) %>%
  mutate_all(na_if, "") # to retain NA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the values to combine in a vector and change the `name` value of it. You can then aggregate them using `group_by` and `across`.

```
library(dplyr)

values_to_combine <- c('A.', 'Ab')

df %>%
  group_by(name = replace(name, name %in% values_to_combine, 'A.')) %>%
  summarise(across(x:z, ~toString(na.omit(.))))

#   name  x     y     z    
#  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 A.    c     r     n    
#2 C.    m     o     w
```

Comment: "Error: `across()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs." I get this error

Comment: thank you it does work, however, I found that the other NA cells have become empty cells. I prefer to keep the other NA cells.

Comment: somehow when I change to na.omit(NA)[1], the two rows did not merge.

Comment: Hi, I have edited the orginal questions, which NA in z column replace with a value 'k'.

Comment: I have added dput sample of my data

Comment: @FH Thank you. Can you try using `~toString(na.omit(.)[1])` in `across` ? Does that help?

Comment: thank you it does work, however, I notice that the NA changes from italic grey NA to NA in my Rstudio. Is it the same?

Comment: I think the `NA`'s have turned into character. If you store the output from above code in `res`. Use `res <- type.convert(res, as.is = TRUE)` to convert the string `NA` to actual `NA`.

Comment: it does return back as is using type.convert thank you

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your `coalesce` criteria is first letter/alphabet of name, (becuase if it would have been only 2 rows to combine that's not much of effort anyways), you could do it like this also

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% group_by(GRP = substr(name, 1, 1)) %>%
  summarise(name = first(name),
            across(!name, ~ paste(na.omit(.))), .groups = 'drop')

# A tibble: 2 x 5
  GRP   name  x     y     z    
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 A     A.    c     r     n    
2 C     C.    m     o     w
```